# .htacess - disallow uploading of files containing certain characters within filename

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, upload, block

I'm wondering if it's possible, via .htaccess to disallow the uploading of files that contain certain characters within the filename?

The first question you'll want to ask is "Why would you want to do this?".

Of late, I've noticed an increasing number of files within my CentOS root level /tmp folder along the lines of phpf98s76hfsd (all files are prefixed php). These are being uploaded via a number of old Joomla installations - v1.0.x, v1.5.x and even 2.5.x.

The point of these hacker-bot attacks is to upload files to the Joomla images folder and then rename them with a .php extension and run them. Each of these files is a variation on a hack to do various nasties to the server.

I've taken steps to stop any .php execution within the images folder on all these Joomla installs, so to all intents and purposes, these installations are safe from this hack.

However, it's a tad annoying that the bots are still uploading dozens of these files to the /tmp folder day after day. It's taking up bandwidth, and I have to purge them from time to time too.

The best solution is to replace the Joomla install with the latest version, and thus close this hack. However, that would involve many many hours of unpaid work- understandably the clients don't want to pay for something that gives them nothing, and cutting them loose would mean losing revenue.

I've already taken reparative steps toward blocking this 'hole' as recommended on several websites, but nevertheless, these files in /tmp keep on coming.

So, a harsh but workable solution of blocking the uploads at a more authoritative level is called for, until I can either get people to pay for an upgrade, or I bite the bullet and do them free of charge.

Not even sure if an .htaccess statement would work here? 
It might have to be something at root /tmp level instead...

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: No, there's no `.htaccess` workaround. You had to inspect the POST payload, which only `mod_security` is able to. The `/tmp` files are a necessity of PHPs file/CGI receival mechanism and otherwise irrelevant; only checking the intended target filename in a PHP script would make sense.

Comment: @TimWright Why don't you make a little bash script that takes joomla patch and patch all the files found that match with it? This way you would probably lose 10 minutes or less of your time to sleep better at night without having to worry that something can potentially go wrong and make you lose countless time of work putting backup back or fixing things while client's site are offline and they are leaving you which in either case you would lose revenue.

Comment: If you are not a script programmer really you could make a cron job to remove all files like /tmp/php* every 5 minutes for example -- an idea if nothing else seems to work

Comment: @JeffClayton probably would not help as after its uploaded its moved to a folder within the client's account, what is left within the /tmp is nothing more than garbage.

Comment: Linux checks file type by the file header not filename like Windows-based systems. It might be a possibility to edit the image upload program so that if it does not find files of different image types it refuses to upload them, deletes them, or changes where they go to /dev/null. The first of those would be the best of course.